# Delete S3 bucket in a strange state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a problem with removing S3 bucket with the following ERROR state (check this image).

[image]
I tried to remove it via aws cli but the result is of course:

```
aws s3 rb s3://hierarchy --force  
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

I can't change anything (bucket policy, etc.) on this bucket.

I have to mention that I'm administrator and have all privileges on the AWS account.

Google does not help me. I would like to know if is it possible to remove bucket like this.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there is a Bucket Policy containing a `Deny` statement that is preventing your access.

Find somebody who has access to the Root credentials, which should be able to delete it.

If that fails, contact AWS Support.

Comment: Bucket Policy of this bucket does not contain a deny statement. Probably I will contact AWS Support.